# Can a portable executable have direct absolute references to external libraries in the code segment, not via IAT?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, portable-executable

If I call Win32 API functions from my C++ code like in the following example:

```
fSuccess = WriteFile( 
  hPipe,                  // pipe handle 
  lpvMessage,             // message 
  cbToWrite,              // message length 
  &cbWritten,             // bytes written 
  NULL);                  // not overlapped
```

then the Visual C++ compiler will translate those calls into absolute references to the import address table (IAT) in the data segment. The IAT itself will contain the actual absolute addresses to the external libraries which contains that Win32 API function. In the example above for the `WriteFile` function this external library is `kernel32.dll`.

If I modify one entry in the IAT at run-time such that it points to a different library/function, then all of the calls to that function in my original C++ will also change. I would like only some of them to change. Or to make it such that a certain Win32 API function does not even appear in the IAT at all, but it is directly referenced by the code segment.

How can I do that? Can I somehow force the compiler to contain a direct absolute reference to an external library in the code segment, instead of an indirect reference via the IAT?

Comment: OK, you are right, I use C++

Comment: You cannot know in advance of loading the module, where it will load, or indeed where the functions will be. You could import the same function multiple times, have say two IAT entries for the same function. Then redirect only one.

Comment: @IInspectable: According to your statement it is in fact language-agnostic, because the WinAPI can be used from other languages as well if they follow the ABI. So removing bolth tags would already be rectified. But OP states he has a problem with his C++ function, so the C++ tag was acceptable, but not C. With your stereotype "arguments", one always had to add C and Assembler tags, because the underlying libraries and OS used both of them. Not to forget algorithm-tag, etc. That is certainly not the intention of tagging questions. But I'll leave you playing big game-master for now.

Comment: @Olaf: The Windows API is **not** language agnostic. It just doesn't make a difference, whether it is called from C or C++. It does make a difference when calling it from Python, Delphi, or C#, for example. Using [tag:c++] and [tag:c] tags is thus appropriate, and not at all redundant (as you keep implying).

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable I had the same impression that is why I used both C and C++. Too bad that I got 2 down votes for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like only some of them to change. Or to make it such that a certain Win32 API function does not even appear in the IAT at all, but it is directly referenced by the code segment.
>
> How can I do that?

To do that, you have to access the functions dynamically at run-time using `LoadLibrary()`/`GetModuleHandle()` and `GetProcAddress()` (or your compiler's delay-load wrapper, if it has one), instead of static linking to the functions at compile-time.  For example:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_WRITEFILE)(HANDLE, LPCVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD, LPOVERLAPPED);
LPFN_WRITEFILE lpWriteFile = (LPFN_WRITEFILE) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), "WriteFile");
fSuccess = lpWriteFile( 
  hPipe,                  // pipe handle 
  lpvMessage,             // message 
  cbToWrite,              // message length 
  &cbWritten,             // bytes written 
  NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks @remy-lebeau for your answer. However, now if someone hooks `GetProcAddress` or `GetModuleHandle` then they will be able to change the behavior of the code you wrote as well, right?

Comment: Technically yes. These are your only options, though. To access a function in an external library, you either static link to it via the IAT, or you dynamically load it via `GetProcAddress()`. Both can be hooked/patched at run-time, so you can't guard against either one being modified.

Comment: OK, thanks! I was hoping there would be another way.